# How to export a large MySQL table

Tags: mysql, export

I currently using `mysqldump` command as follows

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h hostName database tableName > dump.sql
```

and it fails with emitting the following error

```
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `table_name` at row: 1652788
```

Is there any other way (perhaps a parameter to `mysqldump` or etc) for exporting large `MySQL` tables?

Comment: Probably need to increase `max_allowed_packet`. That's the most common cause of this error with mysqldump.

Comment: Go to your server and run the query `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'UPTIME';` This is the time in seconds since the last start/restart of MySQL.  It is possible that you have data corruption, causing the server to crash during this dump, in which case the displayed uptime will be very small.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter  `--single-transaction` to the mysql dump command if you are using innodb engine. This will eliminate locks on the table and possible connection timeouts.

Also, ensure that you have given sufficient values for max packet size, and innodb lock wait timeout